# Extend Array.push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extend a specific array with custom push method:

```js
let instance = {
  'queue': []
};

instance.initQueue = () => {
  let _this = instance;

  _this['queue'].push = func => {
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
      // default
      Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);

      // process
      _this.processQueue();
    }
  };

  _this.processQueue();
};

instance.processQueue = () => {
  let _this = instance;

  _this['queue'].forEach((func, idx, obj) => {
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
      func.call(func);
    }

    obj.splice(idx, 1);
  });
};

instance.initQueue();
instance.queue.push(() => console.log(1))
```

While I'm trying to trigger the push method (`instance.queue.push(() => console.log(1));`, nothing happen. If I'll wrap the `initQueue` function with a timeout - it's work:

```
setTimeout(() => { instance.initQueue(); }, 100);
```

Any reasonable explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: you dont have to write `['queue']`, just use `.queue`

Comment: not answer, but I'd like to know why you don't use normal function + `this` but arrow function + `_this`?

Comment: arrow functions don't have `arguments`

Comment: @appleapple and @Dimava, I'm working with google closure as a compiler, and it has some restrictions on code writing. If I write the word queue without quotes, the name won't save (after minify), and using `this` is not safe.

Comment: @RonZ using `this` is not safe? why you think so?

Comment: @appleapple you can use it but the compiler raising `WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object` as a warning and it's annoying.

Comment: just add to @adiga, it has no `this` either.

Comment: @RonZ as my last comment (which should be one above) shows, the `this` is `global this` in your case (the compiler is correct, and your code is wrong)

Comment: Also I don't think you should extend `Array` while you have write two methods (initQueue and processQueue) on the surrounding instance. (You probably should never do this, tbh)

Comment: You are right about the `this` and `arguments` inside the arrow function. But, as I mentioned, using `_this` as a pointer to the `instance` object was intended to avoid using global this and any such confusing while minifying the code (google does it). About the queue itself, the `processQueue` is running only while some flags are turning true, so I'm pushing functions and data and executing them only while they are ready (this is only a small part of the code).

Comment: @RonZ if you mean https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-this , then you get it wrong.

Comment: @RonZ just a reminder, if you don't tag me I wouldn't receive notification.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the obvious syntax errors, your code seems to be working:

```
let instance = {
  'queue': []
};

instance.initQueue = () => {
  let _this = instance;

  _this['queue'].push = (func,...rest) => {
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
      // default
      Array.prototype.push.apply(_this['queue'], [func, ...rest]);

      // process
      _this.processQueue();
    }
  };

  _this.processQueue();
};

instance.processQueue = () => {
  let _this = instance;

  _this['queue'].forEach((func, idx, obj) => {
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
      func.call(func);
    }

    obj.splice(idx, 1);
  });
};

instance.initQueue();
instance.queue.push(() => console.log(1))
```

The functions are being called as soon as they're pushed in the queue, that's because of:

```
// process
_this.processQueue();
```

You can remove it to control the processing of the queue yourself.